# Android Square Wave

Tags: java, android, waveform, synthesizer

I'm currently trying to make an oscillator than can create multiple waveforms, however my square wave method is generating errors, i'm probably making some stupid mistakes but any help would be appreciated. Heres my code:

```
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioTrack;

/**
* Created by Jack on 16/01/2017.
*/

public class PlayWave {

private final int SAMPLE_RATE = 44100; //maximum sample rate Audiotrack can use
private AudioTrack mAudio;
int buffsize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
private int sampleCount;

public PlayWave() {

    mAudio = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                            buffsize, AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
}

public void setWave (int frequency) {

    sampleCount = (int) ((float) SAMPLE_RATE/frequency);
    short samples[] = new short[sampleCount]; //array to hold samples
    int amplitude = 32767; //
    double twoPi = 8. * Math.atan(1.); //twoPi calculated as the arctangent of 1 multiplied by 8
    double phase = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0;  i < sampleCount;  i++) {
        samples[i] = (short) (amplitude * Math.sin(phase));
        phase += twoPi * frequency/SAMPLE_RATE;
    }
    mAudio.write(samples, 0, sampleCount);
}

public void setSquareWave (int frequency) {
    sampleCount = (int) ((float) SAMPLE_RATE/frequency);
    short samples[] = new short[sampleCount];
    int amplitude = 32767;
    double phase = 0.0;
    double twoPi = 8. * Math.atan(1.);
    for (int i = 0; i < buffsize; i++) {
        short s = (amplitude * Math.sin(phase));
        if (s > 0.0) {
            samples[i] = 32767;
        };

        if (s < 0.0) {
            samples[i] = -32767;
        }
        phase += twoPi * frequency / samples; //this loop causes errors
    }
}

public void start () {
    mAudio.reloadStaticData();
    mAudio.setLoopPoints(0, sampleCount, -1);
    mAudio.play();
}

public void stop () {
    mAudio.stop();
}
}
```

Comment: Can you add the errors to the post so we can see them?

Comment: I've commented the loop that causes errors, its this loop in particular.             
    
    for (int i = 0; i < buffsize; i++) {
        short s = (amplitude * Math.sin(phase));
        if (s > 0.0) {
            samples[i] = 32767;
        };

        if (s < 0.0) {
            samples[i] = -32767;
        }
        phase += twoPi * frequency / samples; //this loop causes errors
    }

Comment: Yes, but what errors? Without a stacktrace, just saying you get "errors" is pretty meaningless.

Comment: Apologies, i'm fairly new to Stackoverflow, the '>' operator can't be used for this declaration (s > 0.0) as 's' is a short and 0.0 is a double

Comment: Cast it to a short then? (s > (short) 0.0)

Comment: Knew it was a stupid error, thanks very much